# Lenovo L450 trackpoint does not work.

Tags: 16.04, drivers, hardware, trackpoint

So I had installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my ThinkPad. However, sometimes the trackpoint did not work when I first switched on the laptop. Now it never works. Neither the trackpoint nor the trackpoint buttons. Any solutions coming up to mind?
Thanks